# Check if SERVICE is running VBNET

Tags: vb.net, service, status

I want to know if a service is running (VBNET) to return a false or true value

I found other questions with this but the codes didnt work for me..

Thanks you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [service controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to determine whether the service is running or not.

```
For Each s As ServiceController In ServiceController.GetServices()
    If s.ServiceName = "yourservicename" AndAlso s.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
           Return True
    End If
Next
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't `Return New ServiceController("your service name").Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running` be faster? It just requires one line. :)

Comment: @EnriqueGarcía Dont forget to mark the question as answered by clicking the tick next to the question - It's helpful for other users with similar problems searching for an answer - AND it gives the person who answered the question some reputation. Cheers

Comment: @VisualVincent - It might be shorter from a code perspective, but creating the instance inline will not result its `Dispose` method being called.   The instance will just float around until it is finally collected.  It should be created in a `Using` block.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : It's a little hard demonstrating that in the comments, but yes. You are right.

Comment: You have to add a reference in the PROJECT references to System.ServiceProcess.dll first and then add "Imports System.ServiceProcess", else ServiceController is not found. Further I have added a return False after the Next and created a function with a string parameter for "yourservicename".